# Zoom to Postcode QGIS Plugin error: ""

Tags: qgis, python, syntax, unboundlocalerror

When trying to use the ZoomToPostcode plugin in QGIS 2.16.2 Nødebo, after inputting a postcode to jump to I am prompted to download updated postcode files. Clicking Yes generates a "Unable to download file" dialog, and nothing else.

The Python Console outputs the following (username redacted for privacy):

```
File "C:/Users/xxx/.qgis2/python/plugins\ZoomToPostcode\zoomtopostcode.py", line 138, in check_pkl
    self.update_pcode_option()

File "C:/Users/xxx/.qgis2/python/plugins\ZoomToPostcode\zoomtopostcode.py", line 176, in update_pcode_option
    self.download_pkl()

File "C:/Users/xxx/.qgis2/python/plugins\ZoomToPostcode\zoomtopostcode.py", line 209, in download_pkl
    pcode_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_temp)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'zip_temp' referenced before assignment
```

How can I resolve this, and have a functioning postcode search function?

Comment: works fine on qgis 2.18.7 / plugin version 0.5 / ubuntu. if you're using an older version of the plugin, try upgrading it using the plugin manager. if you are using the latest version it might be a windows / network related issue

Comment: Odd.. All other plugins work without error, I have full permissions in the QGIS folder/subfolders. I'm at a loss!

Comment: tried on a different machine; works there too. Are you on a corporate network that uses a proxy? That might prevent the direct download from happening. I see you're on Windows.  The file is a binary file, so it might be quarantined / blocked by Anti-Virus or if company IT is set up to prevent random downloads of binary files from the internet.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I opened the .py and accessed the .zip file directly and was presented with a prompt before downloading. After this initial prompt - no problem to download in the browser, however it still doesn't work within QGIS..